# How to insert data in partition table which is not defined in partition?

Tags: oracle, partitioning

Anybody can tell me how can we insert data in partitioned table which is not satisfying partitioning condition.

Comment: by definition, that would seem impossible!

Comment: You could do that with exchange partition without validation. However, the partition elimination algorithm won't be able to find the data later. Can you be more specific about your situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you will get a ORA-14400 error:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t (ID NUMBER)
  2  PARTITION BY RANGE (ID)
  3  (  PARTITION t1 VALUES LESS THAN (100),
  4     PARTITION t2 VALUES LESS THAN (200)
  5  );

Table created

SQL> insert into t values (1);

1 row inserted

SQL> insert into t values (201);

insert into t values (201)
            ~
ORA-14400: inserted partition key does not map to any partition
```

To avoid this, you could use a default partition with `LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)`:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t (ID NUMBER)
  2  PARTITION BY RANGE (ID)
  3  (  PARTITION t1 VALUES LESS THAN (100),
  4     PARTITION t2 VALUES LESS THAN (200),
  5     PARTITION tmax VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)
  6  );

Table created
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to range-partitioned tables and are using 11g, look into defining the tables with interval partitioning.  This is similar to range partitioning except that Oracle will create new partitions or split existing partitions automatically for you.  If you are on an earlier release then Vincent's suggestion of creating a MAXVALUE partition is the answer for range partitioning.